# JavaScript. Help copying text from x.path and inserting into a popup text box

Tags: javascript, automation

I am trying to create a script to insert a sentence into a pop-up box. The sentence will remain the same, with only the person's name changing.

I select a check box on the webpage, copy the person's name from the web page using the ClassName (also tried xPath), select the upload button and finally, enter a sentence with the person's name inserted. Everything works fine until I insert the code to copy the name.

I activate the script from a bookmark in firefox as this will be the first of many scripts, and it is in a convenient place when working.

I thought this would be simple, but it is causing me some problems. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
document.getElementById("1234").click();
NAME = document
    .getElementsByClassName("CLASS_NAME");
    .getText()
    .then(function (value) {
        return value;
    });
document.getElementById("UploadBoxButton").click();
document.getElementById("Notes").value = "Hello " + NAME + ". How are you?";
document.getElementById("Notes").click();
```

Solved:

```
async function example() {
    let NAME = document.querySelector("CSS PATH").textContent;
    let CANDIDATE = NAME.trim()
    document.getElementById("ELEMENTID").click();
    document.getElementById("ELEMENTID").click();
    document.getElementById("ELEMENTID").value = "Hello " + CANDIDATE;
}
example()
```

Comment: There is not enough code shown to debug your issue.  Add all the relevant code to the post if you want helpful responses.  That said you have a few bugs in your code snippet. `getElementsByClassName()`  does not return a promise and not sure where `getText()` handler comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the problem exactly ? NAME hasn't the expected value ?
I think this is due to the use of async function. I mean, when NAME is called to set Notes value, `getText()` has probably not finished to be call asynchronously.
Moreover, where does `getText()` come from ? Can't you simply use :

```js
document.querySelector("#1234").click();
const NAME = document.querySelector(".CLASS_NAME").textContent;
document.querySelector("#UploadBoxButton").click();
document.querySelector("#Notes").value = "Hello " + NAME + ". How are you?";
document.querySelector("#Notes").click();
```

And what is `Notes` ? Are you sure you can change its value like this ? Otherwise, try this :

```js
document.querySelector("#Notes").textContent = "Hello " + NAME + ". How are you?";
```

Comment: NAME had no value, and the code would not run without an error.
"Notes" is the Element Id. I should have changed that.
I have solved my problem with your help. I needed to use the CSS Path to copy the text without errors. I also needed to use textContent rather than getText.

Comment: Happy to have helped you, don't hesitate to vote for my answer if you think it has been useful :)